# Sending SOAP request with MessageCallback and MessageExtractor

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-ws

When sending a `SOAP` request through Spring's [`WebServiceTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html), I would like to provide my payload and perform operation on both the request and the response of it. This is because I need some details from the headers of the request/response.

In the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html) I have found it's possible to alter the request with a [`WebServiceMessageCallback`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceMessageCallback.html) and the response with a [`WebServiceMessageExtractor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceMessageExtractor.html).

The problem I'm having is that the [`WebServiceTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html) seems to *choose* between providing a *payload* and providing `MessageCallback`/`MessageExtractor`.

With that, I mean there are the following methods available:

- `marshalSendAndReceive(Object requestPayload, WebServiceMessageCallback requestCallback)`
- `sendAndReceive(WebServiceMessageCallback requestCallback, WebServiceMessageExtractor<T> responseExtractor)`
- `sendAndReceive(WebServiceMessageCallback requestCallback, WebServiceMessageCallback responseCallback)`

But nothing to provide **all three**. So providing the **payload**, a [`WebServiceMessageCallback`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceMessageCallback.html) for operations on the request and a [`WebServiceMessageCallback`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceMessageCallback.html)/[`WebServiceMessageExtractor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceMessageExtractor.html) for operations on the response.

In the documentation they do provide the following snippet:

```
public void marshalWithSoapActionHeader(final Source s) {
    final Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    webServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
    public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) {
        transformer.transform(s, message.getPayloadResult());
    },
    new WebServiceMessageExtractor() {
        public Object extractData(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException
            // do your own transforms with message.getPayloadResult()
            //     or message.getPayloadSource()
        }
    });
}
```

But passing your payload into an innerclass just to pass in a payload doesn't seem like clean code.

It doesn't really seem logical that you can provide a payload and callback for tampering the request, but not the response. Or tampering the request and response without providing a payload. How would I go about if I'd like to send a payload and access both the request and response?

Comment: Why don't you use a `ClientInterceptor` for this? What is it you cannot do in an interceptor? You should be only working with the payload and shouldn't be setting headers/retrieving headers in the `WebServiceMessageCallback` (that is for messages as the name indicates).

Comment: @M.Deinum That is actually a better idea. I hadn't thought of this, mostly because I read *"To accommodate the setting of SOAP headers and other settings on the message, the WebServiceMessageCallback interface gives you access to the message after it has been created, but before it is sent."* in the documentation regarding the `WebServiceMessageCallback ` but nothing about a `ClientInterceptor`. If you formulate it as an answer I'll gladly accept.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. If it simply the `SoapAction` to set you might want to modify the message, if it is getting more complex and requires setting plain http headers or something else you might be better of using a interceptor, especially if it is required by default instead of a per message basis.

Comment: @M.Deinum In my case, I need to read and store various properties from the `SOAP` header. I now have an `ActionCallback` as `WebServiceMessageCallback` just to create a WS-A compliant request, but logic regarding reading and storing other headers has been moved to an interceptor. Since it should be done during every request using that template anyway. Thank you